# multiple select boxes with same options - require unique selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with 3 select boxes. Each select box has the same options. I want to require that you have to select a different option for each select box. For example, let's say the options are "cat", "dog" and "bird". If someone selects "bird" in the first select box, I want to disable or hide that option from the other two boxes. If they change their selection, then "bird" will be enabled or unhidden again.

```
<select id="box1">
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<select id="box2">
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<select id="box3">
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>
```

I assume I can do this with jquery onchange but I'm not sure how to require the unique selection across different select boxes.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    // If option is selected, disable it in all other select boxes. If option is deselected, reenable it in all other select boxes.
})
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) Top To Bottom Priority Approach**

The **flow must be top to bottom**. This also means when ever the user changes the dropdown value all the next dropdown's which come after it must be reset. Having said this, here is my code snippet.

```js
HandleDropdowns($('#box1'));  //initially call this function to handle the dropdowns by passing the first dropdown as parameter
 
$('select').on('change', function() {
  HandleDropdowns($(this)); // handle all dropdowns on any change event.
});

function HandleDropdowns(element) {      
  var $element = element;
  var value = $element.val();

  $element.nextAll().val('');  //using nextAll lets reset all the following dropdowns
  $element.nextAll().attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //disable all the following dropdowns.
  HandleOptions(); // call this function to toggle the options 

  if (value.length) {
    $element.next().removeAttr('disabled'); // only if this dropdown has some selection enable the next dropdown.
  }
}

function HandleOptions() {
  $('option').removeAttr('disabled'); //reset all the options to be available
  $.each($('select'), function() { //loop from top to bottom and disable the options one by one.
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length) {
      $(this).nextAll().find('option[value="' + value + '"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="box1">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<select id="box2">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<select id="box3">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>
```

---

**2) All Select Box With Same Priority Approach**

In this approach when ever the user selects a value we check if any other dropdown has the same value, If yes reset it else do nothing. Below is a working sample.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  HandleDropdowns($(this));
});

function HandleDropdowns(element) {
  var $element = element;
  var value = $element.val();
  
  $.each($('select').not($element), function() { //loop all remaining select elements
    var subValue = $(this).val();
    if (subValue === value) { // if value is same reset
      $(this).val('');
      console.log('resetting ' + $(this).attr('id')); // demo purpose
    }
  });  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="box1">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<select id="box2">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<select id="box3">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be the best answer. But does it have to reset everything when you go back and change the first selection? Is there a way that it only resets the options you didn't choose?

Comment: @LBF that would again introduce complexity. For example if first dropdown was cat, second was dog ,third was bird.. now if I go-ahead and select dog in first that means I need to clear off the second dropdown . Which means third is still left with bird as selected, But now there is a possibility that I can choose bird in second dropdown that means bow I will have to clear the third .. This is the reason I suggested to reset the following dropdown when one dropdown changes value.

Comment: @LBF or are you looking for a solution which is not top to bottom style. But rather gives same priority to all the dropdowns?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a solution that gives the same priority to all dropdowns. I suppose @Melvin's answer takes that approach, but it doesn't work properly when you try to change your answer. Hmm...

Comment: @LBF added a different approach as you requested.

Comment: Your second example is exactly what I was hoping to do! Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy, How to do this in multi-select dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
  $("select").find("option").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("select").not(this).find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: @Downvoters please explain reason so i can correct for future.

Comment: This code is not consistent..what happens when I select a last remaining option in the last `select` element, The first two element now disables only this option where as the other two options are enabled for both the dropdowns. Which means now in the second dropdown I can choose the value same as the first dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can use onchange listener and evaluate the results simultaneously. Also add an reset button cause once three get selected, it becomes bottle neck case.

The working code is given below

```js
function changeSelect(elements) {
  var values = {};
  elements.forEach(function(item){
    values[item.id] = item.value;
  });
  elements.forEach(function(item){
    for(var i = 0; i < item.children.length; i++) {
      for(ids in values) {
        if(item.id != ids && item.children[i].value == values[ids]) {
          item.children[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

function resetSelection(elements) {
  elements.forEach(function(item){
    item.value = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < item.children.length; i++) {
      item.children[i].style.display = '';
    }
  });
}

var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
var box3 = document.getElementById('box3');
var boxArray = [box1, box2, box3];
boxArray.forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener('change', changeSelect.bind(undefined,boxArray));
});
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', resetSelection.bind(undefined,boxArray));
```

```html
<select id="box1">
    <option value="">Select An Option</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<select id="box2">
    <option value="">Select An Option</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>

<select id="box3">
    <option value="">Select An Option</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
</select>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm hoping to find a way to do this without a reset button, but I understand why it was necessary. It's just a bit confusing if you try to go back and change your answer without noticing that you have to reset.