# Alert if selected option are already selected in other select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I need to alert if option is selected in other select option value. i disabled the option if selected but it can not insert into database because of disabled attribute. so i only want to alert.

```
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_2_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_3_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>

<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_4_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_5_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
```

This change function disabled the option if other select option is selected. When I change to alert it not working. How to only alert if selected in other select option.

```
$('.input_slip_no').on('change', function() {
  var selected_options = $('.input_slip_no').map(function(){
    return this.value
  }).get();

  $('.input_slip_no option').each(function(index) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', $.inArray($(this).val(), selected_options) != -1);
  });
});
```

Comment: I suppose you need __one__ select with `multiple` attribute.

Comment: what are you trying to alert on what event?

Comment: @guradio i want to alert this value already selected please select other option

Comment: replace `$(this).attr('disabled',true);` with `$(this).val('');alert('already selected');`

Comment: you can hide the other select option  if the option is already selected on first option tag by using visiblity attribute.

Comment: Also may be this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/41125005/2592042

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Can you please show me the code how to hide

Comment: @Dev what should you hide? The already selected options?

Comment: @Dev You can check my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go with the jQuery selector as below,

**Note**: I have added empty element as initial selected value since the same value has been selected in your sample above.

```js
$('.input_slip_no').change(function(){
  
  var selected = $(this).val();
  if(selected) {
    var otherSelected = $('.input_slip_no').not($(this)).find('option[value="' + selected + '"]:selected');
    
    if(otherSelected.length > 0) {
      alert('Option is already selected');
      $(this).val('');
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_2_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value=""></option>    
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_3_slip_no" required="required">         
  <option value=""></option>    
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>

<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_4_slip_no" required="required">        
  <option value=""></option>     
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
<select class="input_slip_no form-control" name="slip_no[]" id="ID_5_slip_no" required="required">     
  <option value=""></option>        
  <option value="SYS0001">SYS0001</option>
  <option value="SYS0002">SYS0002</option>
  <option value="SYS0003">SYS0003</option>
  <option value="SYS0004">SYS0004</option>
  <option value="SYS0005">SYS0005</option>
  <option value="SYS0006">SYS0006</option>
  <option value="SYS0007">SYS0007</option>
  <option value="SYS0008">SYS0008</option>
  <option value="SYS0009">SYS0009</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this link:

```
$('.ddControl').change(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<$('.ddControl').length;i++){
  debugger;
    if($(this).attr('id') != $($('.ddControl')[i]).attr('id'))
    {
        if($(this).val() == $($('.ddControl')[i]).val())
      {
        alert('Option is already selected');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/14tz79a2/6/)